# How to plot lines parallel to the x-axis with a certain offset given by data in an input file with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I calculated the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian for the 1D-hydrogen atom in atomic units with the Fourier-Grid-Hamiltonian method in a nice little Fortran program.

All the eigenvalues found between -1 and 0 (the bound states) are saved into a file line by line like this:

```
-0.50016671392950229
-0.18026105614262633
-0.11485673263086937
-4.7309305955423042E-002
-4.7077108902158216E-002
```

As the number of found eigenvalues differs depends on the stepsize my program uses, the number of entries in the file can vary (in theory, there are infinite ones).

I now want to plot the values from the file as a line parallel to the x-axis with the offset given by the values read from file. 
I also want to be able to plot the data only up to a certain line number, as the values get really close to each other the further you come to zero and they cannot be distinguished by eye anymore.

(Here e.g. it would make sence to plot the first four entries, the fifth is already too close to the previous one)

I know that one can plot lines parallel to the x axis with the command `plot *offset*` but I don't know how to tell gnuplot to use the data from the file. So far I had to manually plot the values.

As a second step I would like to plot the data only in a certain x range, more concrete between the points of intersection with the harmonic potential used for the numeric solution `V(x) = -1/(1+abs(x))`

The result should look like this:
[scheme of the desired plot (lookalike)](https://www.learner.org/courses/physics/visual/img_lrg/energy_levels.jpg)

The closest I got to, was with

```
plot -1/(1+abs(x)),-0.5 title 'E0',-0.18 title 'E1', -0.11 title 'E2'
```

which got me the following result:
[my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnRdb.png)

Hope you guys can help me, and I'm really curios whether gnuplot actually can do the second step I described!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach may be to get data from "energy.dat" (as given in the question) with `system` and `cat` commands (so assuming a Un*x-like system...) and select V(x) and E at each x via `max`:

```
set key bottom right
set yr [-1:0.2]
set samples 1000

Edat = system( "cat energy.dat" )

max(a,b) = ( a > b ) ? a : b
V(x) = -1/(1+abs(x))

plot for [ E in Edat ] \
     max(V(x),real(E)) title sprintf("E = %8.6f", real(E)) lw 2, \
     V(x) title "V(x) = -1/(1+|x|)" lc rgb "red" lw 2
```

[image]

If we change the potential to `V(x) = -abs(cos(x))`, the plot looks pretty funny (and the energy levels are of course not correct!)

[image]

---

More details about the script:

- `max` is not a built-in function in Gnuplot, but a user-defined function having two formal arguments. So for example, we may define it as

  `mymax( p, q ) = ( p > q ) ? p : q`

with any other names (and use `mymax` in the `plot` command). Next, the `?` symbol is a [ternary operator](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node58.html) that gives a short-hand notation for an `if`...`else` construct. In a pseudo-code, it works as

```
function max( a, b ) {
    if ( a > b ) then
        return a
    else
        return b
    end
}
```

This way, `max(V(x),real(E))` selects the greater value between `V(x)` and `real(E)` for any given `x` and `E`.

- Next, `Edat = system( "cat energy.dat" )` tells Gnuplot to run the shell command "cat energy.dat" and assign the output to a new variable `Edat`. In the above case, `Edat` becomes a string that contains a sequence of energy values read in from "energy.dat". You can check the contents of `Edat` by `print( Edat )`. For example, it may be something like

  `Edat = "-0.11 -0.22 ... -0.5002"`
- `plot for [ E in Edat ] ...` loops over words contained in a string  `Edat`. In the above case, `E` takes a string "-0.11", "-0.22", ..., "-0.5002" one-by-one. `real(E)` converts this string to a floating-point value. It is used to pass `E` (a character string) to any mathematical function.
- The basic idea is to draw a truncated potential above E, max(V(x),E), for each value of E. (You can check the shape of such potential by `plot max(V(x),-0.5)`, for example). After plotting such curves, we redraw the potential `V(x)` to make it appear as a single potential curve with a different color.
- `set samples 1000` increases the resolution of the plot with 1000 points per curve. 1000 is arbitrary, but this seems to be sufficient to make the figure pretty smooth.

Comment: That looks rather nicely!
In order to understand myself what you did here, it would be nice if you could explain the `max(a,b) = ( a > b ) ? a : b` part more detailed to me, I neither found a nice tutorial that explains that keyword nor understand why it is doing what it is doing ;)
Thank you for the beautiful solution!

Comment: Hi, I have added some additional info about the script. Because I'm using Gnuplot very empirically, my explanation may be not very good or accurate in various parts, so please consult other pages also for more info. (FYI, I also used Fourier Grid Hamiltonian before, it was very useful :)

Answer (score 2):

As for the first part of your question, you can for example use the `xerrorbars` plotting style as:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'fig.png'

unset key
set xr [-1:1]
set yr [-1:0]

unset bars
plot '-' u (0):($1<-0.1?$1:1/0):(1) w xerrorbars pt 0 lc rgb 'red'
-0.50016671392950229
-0.18026105614262633
-0.11485673263086937
-4.7309305955423042E-002
-4.7077108902158216E-002
e
```

The idea here is to:

1. interpret the energies E as points with coordinates (0,E) and assign to each of them an x-errorbar of width 1 (via the third part of the specification `(0):($1<-0.1?$1:1/0):(1)`)
2. "simulate" the horizontal lines with x-errorbars. To this end, `unset bars` and `pt 0` ensure that Gnuplot displays just plain lines.
3. consider only energies `E<-0.1`, the expressions `$1<-0.1?$1:1/0` evaluates otherwise to an undefined value `1/0` which has the consequence that nothing is plotted for such E.
4. `plot '-'` with explicit values can be of course replaced with, e.g., `plot 'your_file.dat'`

This produces:
[image]

For the second part, it mostly depends how complicated is your function `V(x)`. In the particular case of `V(x)=-1/(1+|x|)`, one could infer directly that it's symmetric around `x=0` and calculate the turning points explicitly, e.g.,

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'fig.png'

fName = 'test.dat'

unset key
set xr [-10:10]
set yr [-1:0]

unset bars

f(x) = -1 / (1+abs(x))
g(y) = (-1/y - 1)

plot \
    f(x) w l lc rgb 'black', \
    fName u (0):($1<-0.1?$1:1/0):(g($1)) w xerrorbars pt 0 lc rgb 'red', \
    fName u (0):($1<-0.1?$1:1/0):(sprintf("E%d", $0)) w labels offset 0, char 0.75
```

which yields

[image]

The idea is basically the same as before, just the width of the errorbar now depends on the y-coordinate (the energy). Also, the `labels` style is used in order to produce explicit labels.